# SharePoint 2013 Migration Project

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I have Project server 2010 in my Share Point 2010 Farm. I have integrated project server with SharePoint. Now I am Migrating SharePoint 2010 Farm to SharePoint 2013.
If I need pwa sites to move over.?

Do I need to have license of Project Server 2013 and integrate it with my SharePoint 2013 farm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to migrate the PWA sites which are in SharePoint content DB. read this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662496.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662104.aspx

You need Project server License, In order to license Project Server 2013, you need the SharePoint 2013 Enterprise License( server + Cal).

Here is the guide for the Project Licensing: https://products.office.com/en-us/project/microsoft-project-licensing